# What's the use of CollectionViewSource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry for asking this silly question.

I am using this framework: MahApps.Metro [here](http://mahapps.com/) (Framework 4.0).

I started using the controls as shown in the project under samples folder [github link](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

In DataGrid I have a problem

My xaml is

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MetroDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserDetailsList}"                                  
              RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
              TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
              HeadersVisibility="All"
              Margin="5"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"
                                Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary"
                                Binding="{Binding Salary}" />

            <controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Salary"
                                                  Binding="{Binding Salary}"
                                                  StringFormat="C"
                                                  Minimum="0" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and in the code behind i added this code,

```
this.DataContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    var vm = args.NewValue as StyleDemoViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(vm.UserDetailsList).GroupDescriptions.Clear();

        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(vm.UserDetailsList).GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription());
    }
};
```

When I commented this code style of `NumericUpDownColumn` in the `Grid` after editing gets changed in a different way and when I used the C# code the same if I edit that column the style (I mean foreground is black in the earlier and white in the later) is different.

That C# code I got it from the github link I mentioned earlier.

Please give an idea of how this code affects the style.

Comment: Whats the reason for down vote ?

Comment: Its whats is happening. I couldn't understand that. It can't be searched and get it. So i asked in SO. Please tell me how to improve this question ?